# Howto in multi thread,call recursively function

Tags: multithreading, delphi, synchronization, delphi-xe3

I wrote a function to recursively search for files that are associated with the objects on the form,I run this function in a separate thread, so the UI thread is not a problem.

How can I with Synchronize, I call a function that has a parameter?

Is the recursive function calls the Synchronize command, I have reasonably correct?

Synchronize mode has the same return all calls?

Comment: I understand the first paragraph, the answer to the second is "You can't, Synchonize is parameterless". The rest of the question doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: to sync with main thread and call a function with 1 or more params, you can do Synchronize(procedure begin MyFunctionWith(Param1, Param2, ParamN); end);

Comment: Thank @GolezTrol, by making sure that friends have said tricks can be implemented. I did not come to mind!I thought Synchronize function is parametrized. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an anonymous method to make the call:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  MyParameter: Integer;
begin
  MyParameter := 42;
  Synchronize(
    procedure
    begin
      MethodWithParameter(MyParameter);
    end
    );
end;
```

Comment: Love anonymous methods just for this possibility :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
...
FMyValue := Xyz;
Synchronize(MyProc);
...

Procedure TMyThread.MyProc;
begin
  VclProc(FMyValue)
end;
```